# form onSubmit event doesn't trigger in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, events, dom-events

This my form component, providing that this a single form of an item-form list the problem is that the form onSubmit is not triggering when submitting the form. The problem happens with all forms of the list. Also, other events like onClick work fine

```
// State vars
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(value.body);

return (
    <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            // doesn't work!
        }}
        className="flex items-center space-x-3"
    >
        <Controls.TextInput
            inputRef={formInputRef}
            inputChange={(e) => {
                handleUpdate(value.id, e.target.value);
                setInputValue(e.target.value);
            }}
            value={inputValue}
            label={label}
        />

        <button type="submit" className="sr-only"></button>

        <div className="flex">
            {/* button for focus state */}
            <IconButton onClick={handleStartStopListening} color="primary" size="small">
                {listeningIcon}
            </IconButton>

            <IconButton onClick={handleDeleteItem} size="small">
                <TrashIcon className="h-6 cursor-pointer text-red-600 " />
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    </form>
);
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by _"doesn't work"_?

Comment: @Phil. for example, if I click on the submit button, the form's onSubmit  handler isn't triggered and the page gets reloaded even if I prevent default the form